# Parsing XML properly

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am working with Songkick API and need to parse the XML data from a URL to grab a nested url and redirect to it.  I can't seem to get the parse the XML properly.  Here is what I have now.

```
1.  <?php
2.  $songkick_artist = $_GET['id'];
3. 
4.  $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
5.  $xmlDoc->load("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.xml?query=$songkick_artist&apikey=songkickapikey"); 
6.
7.  $x = $xmlDoc->documentElement; 
8.  foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item) 
9.  {  
10. print $item->[]  
11. print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br />"; 
12. }
13. ?>
```

I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting T_STRING 
>   or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' on line 10

There are so many ways to parse XML info that I am quite confused right now.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Updated 4-13-11

I changed my code to this now:

```
<?php   
$doc = new DomDocument;

// We must validate the document before referring to the id
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->Load("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.xml?query=$songkick_artist&apikey=songkickapikey");

echo "The element whose id is myelement is: " . 
$doc->getElementById('myelement')->tagName . "\n";
?>
```

and I am getting a 403 forbidden error when $doc->Load("URL"); is fired...

What gives?

Comment: Check your syntax. The error message tells that you have a syntax error on line 10: `print $item->[]`. This has nothing to do with parsing XML in this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure if the API lacked JSON support at the time of this question, but JSON is supported now and is much preferred over XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this figured out.

$request_url = urlencode ("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.xml?query=$songkick_artist&apikey=songkickapikey"); 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("feed not loading");
$artist = $xml->results  ->artist["uri"];

The urlencode is the main key on this since the url will not parse correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a simple parse error.
You lack an ; on line 10. That might solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do in line 10? Your syntag is wrong:
`print $item->[]`
$item is an Object so you can use $item->doSomeMethod() to do doSomeMethod but you can't write $item->[].

Comment: Hi Wesley, I've tried that and it isn't the problem.  It seems MRu is on here but what can I do to get the results I need?